# Appropriateness of the Universal Sentence Encoder model

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, word-embeddings, cosine-similarity

I have a classification problem where the goal is to predict, based on a small paragraph, if an individual is British or not.

The model used for the classification is Universal Sentence Encoder (to transform the paragraph into vectors) and a classifier for the classification.

I would like to show/illustrate that the universal sentence encoder is an appropriate choice for this problem which means that the embedded vectors contain the information about the individual nationality. And I would like to illustrate this by working on the embedded vectors only, I don't want to use the results of the classifier and to say "as the accuracy is good, it means that the universal sentence encoder is a good choice".

I am thinking to take some meaningful cases (a paragraph where the individual is clearly British, another one where the individual is clearly not British and a paragraph where we cannot conclude) and to compute the cosine similarity with the sentence "I am British" and "I am not British". I have not tried yet but my concern is that the paragraphs contain more information than the nationality only.

Any thoughts about this test? What other tests could I do to show that the universal sentence encoder is an appropriate choice?